# Convert total seconds column to hours and minutes

Tags: sql

In our database we have a column that is in total seconds. I would to convert this to hours and minutes.

I tried this and it seems to work. But I don't understand the = 31680**** ? I need all seconds converted for each row not just one value. And where do I insert this into my current query ?

```
SET @TimeinSecond = 31680 -- Change the seconds
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query uses product specific syntax and functionality.

Comment: In PostgreSQL this would be simply `select make_interval(secs => totalseconds)::text from ...;`

Comment: its a relational DB.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't mess around with strings.** Just use `DATEADD`.

```sql
SET @TimeinSecond = 31680 -- Change the seconds

SELECT DATADD(second, @TimeInSecond, CAST('00:00:00' AS time));
```

Answer (score -1):

31680 is just the example value they used, corresponding to 08:48:00.

In a query, assuming you have a column called "TOTALSECONDS", you'd use this:

```
SELECT Totalseconds, RIGHT('0' + CAST(Totalseconds/ 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((Totalseconds/ 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(Totalseconds % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as HMS
FROM PRoduct
```

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ba16fecc-aa8f-4260-a70f-99e835bf0d78

Comment: I tried that and I am getting following error: Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type int, table 'IP_FLWSHT_MEAS', column 'RECORDED_TIME'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Then your column isn't actually a total number of seconds, it's a datetime. Can you post some of your data, and explain how you retrieve seconds from that column?

Comment: this is what I have in my select statement:

Comment: MAX(CASE WHEN FlowsheetValues.FLO_MEAS_ID = '3040100962' THEN 
   MEAS_VALUE END) Notification_Time,
 MAX(  CASE WHEN FlowsheetValues.FLO_MEAS_ID = '4381' THEN MEAS_VALUE END) Response_Time

Comment: so these 2 columns come across I guess as Date\Time but are actually Total Seconds: 31680
28800
42120
42480
50280
50520
NULL
NULL
37200

Comment: These comments are basically not helpful at all. Can you use [sqlfiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com), as I did, to set up a minimal reproducible example?